# Not able to get any callBack when call is finished using UIApplication.shared.open()

Tags: ios, swift, phone-call

```
let number = URL(string: "tel://1234567890")
UIApplication.shared.open(number)
```

when call is finished not able to know when it is finished.
I need call duration time in my project.

Comment: Call back from what, I don’t see how UIApplication knows anything about phone calls? I think you need to research [CallKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit)